Почему юзербот в групповом чате телеграма видит только свои сообщения и сообщения с упоминанием себя?
Использую такой код:
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client
from config import api_id, api_hash

app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message()
async def echo(client, message):
    print(message)
    await message.reply(message.text)

app.run() 

Есть пользователь realnikolai, он получатель сообщений, выводящий полученные сообщения в консоль.
Кроме него есть пользователь realpavelb, который создал чат с id -1002231967193
(хотя почему-то в атрибуте is_creator написано false). Когда он отправил сообщение в этом чате,
то в консоль пришло это сообщение:
{
    "_": "Message",
    "id": 21,
    "from_user": {
        "_": "User",
        "id": 348149609,
        "is_self": false,
        "is_contact": true,
        "is_mutual_contact": true,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "is_support": false,
        "is_premium": false,
        "first_name": "Я",
        "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
        "username": "realpavelb",
        "dc_id": 2,
        "phone_number": "*********",
        "photo": {
            "_": "ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgADrqcxG2lXwBQAEAIAA2lXwBQABHRcMQkGAVS8AAQeBA",            "small_photo_unique_id": "AgADrqcxG2lXwBQ",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgADrqcxG2lXwBQAEAMAA2lXwBQABHRcMQkGAVS8AAQeBA",  
            "big_photo_unique_id": "AgADrqcxG2lXwBQ"
        }
    },
    "date": "2024-06-26 03:20:05",
    "chat": {
        "_": "Chat",
        "id": -1002231967193,
        "type": "ChatType.SUPERGROUP",
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_creator": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "title": "Экспериментальный чат",
        "has_protected_content": false,
        "permissions": {
            "_": "ChatPermissions",
            "can_send_messages": true,
            "can_send_media_messages": true,
            "can_send_other_messages": true,
            "can_send_polls": true,
            "can_add_web_page_previews": true,
            "can_change_info": true,
            "can_invite_users": true,
            "can_pin_messages": true
        }
    },
    "mentioned": false,
    "scheduled": false,
    "from_scheduled": false,
    "has_protected_content": false,
    "text": "Хой",
    "outgoing": false
}

То есть пользователь realnikolai получил полученное сообщение в групповом чате и вывел его в консоль.
Так и должно быть.
Но когда пользователь realpavel опубликовал сообщение в чате с id=-1001072533952,
в консоль не было выведено ничего, как будто пользователь realnikolai его не получил.
А когда пользователь realnikolai отправил в тот же чат своё сообщение,
то он увидел своё сообщение и вывел в консоль:
{
    "_": "Message",
    "id": 153723,
    "from_user": {
        "_": "User",
        "id": 5936165702,
        "is_self": true,
        "is_contact": true,
        "is_mutual_contact": true,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "is_support": false,
        "is_premium": false,
        "first_name": "Николай",
        "status": "UserStatus.ONLINE",
        "next_offline_date": "2024-06-26 03:33:42",
        "username": "realnikolai",
        "dc_id": 2,
        "phone_number": "*********",
        "photo": {
            "_": "ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgAD2cIxG9_n-EgAEAIAA0az0mEBAAPlM1hGMTQTVwAEHgQ",
            "small_photo_unique_id": "AgAD2cIxG9_n-Eg",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgAD2cIxG9_n-EgAEAMAA0az0mEBAAPlM1hGMTQTVwAEHgQ", 
            "big_photo_unique_id": "AgAD2cIxG9_n-Eg"
        }
    },
    "date": "2024-06-26 03:31:26",
    "chat": {
        "_": "Chat",
        "id": -1001072533952,
        "type": "ChatType.SUPERGROUP",
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_creator": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "title": "Хастл",
        "username": "all_hustle",
        "photo": {
            "_": "ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgAD9qoxG6DgMwEAEAIAA0BebesW____JenP6rkgy6EABB4E",
            "small_photo_unique_id": "AgAD9qoxG6DgMwE",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgAD9qoxG6DgMwEAEAMAA0BebesW____JenP6rkgy6EABB4E",            "big_photo_unique_id": "AgAD9qoxG6DgMwE"
        },
        "dc_id": 2,
        "has_protected_content": false,
        "permissions": {
            "_": "ChatPermissions",
            "can_send_messages": true,
            "can_send_media_messages": true,
            "can_send_other_messages": true,
            "can_send_polls": false,
            "can_add_web_page_previews": true,
            "can_change_info": false,
            "can_invite_users": true,
            "can_pin_messages": false
        }
    },
    "reply_to_message_id": 32577,
    "reply_to_message": {
        "_": "Message",
        "id": 32577,
        "from_user": {
            "_": "User",
            "id": 20177056,
            "is_self": false,
            "is_contact": false,
            "is_mutual_contact": false,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "is_bot": false,
            "is_verified": false,
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_scam": false,
            "is_fake": false,
            "is_support": false,
            "is_premium": false,
            "first_name": "AL",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "username": "aloginovpro"
        },
        "date": "2024-01-14 13:07:20",
        "chat": {
            "_": "Chat",
            "id": -1001072533952,
            "type": "ChatType.SUPERGROUP",
            "is_verified": false,
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_creator": false,
            "is_scam": false,
            "is_fake": false,
            "title": "Хастл",
            "username": "all_hustle",
            "photo": {
                "_": "ChatPhoto",
                "small_file_id": "AQADAgAD9qoxG6DgMwEAEAIAA0BebesW____JenP6rkgy6EABB4E",
                "small_photo_unique_id": "AgAD9qoxG6DgMwE",
                "big_file_id": "AQADAgAD9qoxG6DgMwEAEAMAA0BebesW____JenP6rkgy6EABB4E",
                "big_photo_unique_id": "AgAD9qoxG6DgMwE"
            },
            "dc_id": 2,
            "has_protected_content": false,
            "permissions": {
                "_": "ChatPermissions",
                "can_send_messages": true,
                "can_send_media_messages": true,
                "can_send_other_messages": true,
                "can_send_polls": false,
                "can_add_web_page_previews": true,
                "can_change_info": false,
                "can_invite_users": true,
                "can_pin_messages": false
            }
        }
    },
    "mentioned": false,
    "scheduled": false,
    "from_scheduled": false,
    "has_protected_content": false,
    "text": "Экс",
    "outgoing": true
}

Кроме того, в этом же чате с -1001072533952 пользователь realnikolai видит сообщения,
в которых упоминают его (являются ответами на его сообщения).
Вопросы:

**почему realnikolai получает и выводит в консоль только те сообщения
из чата -1001072533952, которые отправил он сам? При этом сообщения
в другом чате он выводит все.
Вопрос: как фильтровать сообщения, приходящие в какую-то конкретную
тему суперчата? Вроде сообщения в pyrogram не имеют атрибута темы
чата.
не обязательный вопрос, но всё же, вдруг знаете: почему сообщение,
отправленное создателем чата -1002231967193 содержит атрибут
"is_creator": false?**

Примечание. Если смотреть в ручную через смартфон, то пользователь realnikolai может и видеть,
и пересылать чужие сообщения. То есть все права есть.
Но программа почему-то их не выводит в консоль.
